# jQuery on() Method with 'keyup' and 'change' arguments doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, event-binding

I'm trying to disable a submit button to check if all the input fields are filled before submitting. The code below works fine on desktop, but it is not working on mobile devices. Am I missing something?

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('button.wof-btn-submit').attr('disabled', true);
$('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) { 
 
        validateInputs();
    });
​
    $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
​
    $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
​
    $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
​
    function validateInputs(){
        var disableButton = false;
​
        var val1 = $('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').val();
        var val2 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').val();
        var val3 = $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').val();
        var val4 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').val();
​
        if(val1.length == 0 || val2.length == 0 || val3.length == 0 || val4.length == 0)
            disableButton = true;
​
        $('button.wof-btn-submit').attr('disabled', disableButton);
    }
});
```

Here is the [link](https://bathandbodyworks-rewards.com/)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can try using the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), which should replace your `change`, `keyup` and `paste` (not sure about `drop`)

Comment: Your events firing right but html btn disabled=false wouldn't work so you should just remove attribute `if(!disableButton){
        $('button.wof-btn-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }`

Comment: @secan, i've replaced input but to no avail, it is not working even on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button.wof-btn-submit').attr('disabled', true);
  $('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {

    validateInputs();
  });
  $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
    validateInputs();
  });
  $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
    validateInputs();
  });
  $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
    validateInputs();
  });

  function validateInputs() {
    var disableButton = false;

    var val1 = $('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').val();
    var val2 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').val();
    var val3 = $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').val();
    var val4 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').val();

    if (val1.length == 0 || val2.length == 0 || val3.length == 0 || val4.length == 0) {
      disableButton = true;
      $('button.wof-btn-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    }

    if (!disableButton) {
      $('button.wof-btn-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wof-form-wrapper">
  <div class="wof-error wof-fgcolor" style="color:#dd0000;border-color:#dd0000;display: none;"></div>

  <div class="wof-form-fields">
    <div>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" data-wof-field="primary_email" class="wof-input" name="wof-email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" data-wof-field="text_2" class="wof-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Transaction Number" data-wof-field="number_1" class="wof-input">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" data-wof-field="text_1" class="wof-input">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="wof-btn-submit wof-color-2" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
    <span>Try your luck</span>
    <div class="wof-loader" style="display: none;">
      <div class="b1"></div>
      <div class="b2"></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </button>

  <div class="wof-response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @fatima, this works just fine on desktop, the issue is on mobile devices, I've used your snippet but the button remain disabled on mobile.

Comment: @Richu Is events firing or ?

Comment: It is firing on desktop( laptop) but apparently it is not working on mobile. 

[link](https://bathandbodyworks-rewards.com/)

Comment: @Richu i think it's failing value check. Try with different values and try to test it. Cause events is firing.

Comment: Nope, it is weird, it works on Blisk and not on chrome.

Comment: Maybe check events support. But i thought change is supported almost everywhere